# Pass Values from one user control to another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, event-handling

I am working on a WPF application, and I looking for a solution on how to pass a integer values either generated or pulled from a database across user controls

For example

- Let's say there is a main window called `WinA`
- it hosts 2 user controls, one called `CustomerDetails` and another `CustomerOrder`
- the `CustomerDetails` user control has a `CustomerID` textbox and a button and some unimportant textboxes to insert values into the database
- `CustomerOrder` has an `OrderID` textbox

We create a customer profile on `CustomerDetails`. When I click the button (on `CustomerDetails`), it would not only save values to the database but also open the `CustomerOrder` user control and should take the value from the `CustomerID` textbox and pass it into the `OrderID` textbox

- Saving values into database, opening a new user control ✔ Done
- Passing value into into another user control ❌ Cannot even start

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this,

If customer order control always initiated and start from customer details (or a common controller/ViewModel), you can inject the data (in form of model/class object) to customer order user control class (See dependency injection articles).

If customer order is open from different places, still you can use dependency injection to inject required information.

You can use event aggregator or binding to populate the value in the scenario where both controls are already open prior to clicking the button

Comment: So the two user control must share this information, usually by both having a reference to the same data structure. In WPF this is usually done via the `DataContext`. Read about MVVM.

Comment: Yep. You'd usually have a viewmodel for the window. A property in that is then in the datacontext for anything in that window ( loosely speaking ) and can be bound.  If there's a bunch of things - say orders - that could be an observablecollection of order in another property. And or  you can have a complex viewmodel as a property if you have a lot of data for something and grouping it or switching it out is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable using get and set inside the code for the control.